# Unable to add transition to a select box in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a input field that has an arrow `onClick` on it it shows a list box, i want to add a transition to this select box on opening and closing it, but nothing is done. What is wrong here?

```css
.combobox-options {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 15em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```js
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    <input role="combobox"  className="combobox-input"/>
    <button
        className={clsx("arrow", isOpen && "down")}
        onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
    </button>
    {isOpen && (
       <ul
          id="combobox-listbox"
          role="listbox"
          className={clsx("combobox-options")}
        >
            {options?.map((option: any, index: any) => {
              return (
                <li>...</li>
              );
            })}
        </ul>
    )}
```

Comment: in your case, animations not work anytime. what is wrong? for using of transition you need to change style for example when user clicked on button, ul hieght goes from 0 to 100px!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `css` when you are using `javascript` to appear and disappear the `ul` element. Remove `isOpen` from around the `ul` element and use it to toggle between CSS classes.

Use the below example as a helper for changing your structure.

```js
className={clsx("combobox-options", !isOpen && "hide")}
```

```css
.combobox-options {
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 15em;
  overflow: hidden;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 0.25em);
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.hide {
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks, but how can i make it fold from up to down?

Comment: @TSDev you're welcome. You can use negative `top` or you can use specific `height` and use `height: 0` in the `hide` selector. example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3E5P/3/

Comment: @Mohammed Reza Khedri, it didn't work, the list is always opening from the middle, and i want it to be folded from up to down

Comment: @TSDev Answer updated. You can use the new CSS.

Comment: i am sorry for bothering you, but how can i make it to fad in and out?

Comment: @TSDev you can use `opacity` for smooth fade in and out of your box.